# persp3d - main title that doesn't rotate?

Tags: r, plot, rgl

Editing to provide more code and a runnable example.

If I open a 3D plot using the following code:

```
library(rgl)

GainTargets = seq(from=1, to=12, by=1)
PredBarTargets = seq(from=3, to=16, by=1)

data=structure(c(1176.18, 1379.34, 1280.67, 1149.02, 1034.01, 1028.74, 
             944.06, 807.54, 715.39, 691.08, 679.14, 644.02, 642.98, 577.61, 
             1004.22, 1238.13, 1216.16, 1104.92, 1032.46, 1038.11, 919.98, 
             855.47, 706.54, 668.51, 665.67, 689.57, 686, 623.82, 729.61, 
             1127.32, 1137.55, 1084.25, 955.15, 1005.86, 955.6, 881.66, 839.93, 
             767.45, 731.49, 727.19, 696.45, 634.52, 377.81, 917.08, 1087.57, 
             1036.17, 920.88, 993.75, 964.35, 848.94, 874.95, 780.58, 725.08, 
             695.12, 709.32, 663.93, 227, 787.53, 949.31, 972.59, 950.3, 946.22, 
             876.33, 881.49, 827.44, 767.66, 755.26, 731.71, 744.37, 692.86, 
             32.65, 404.91, 514.82, 652.8, 697.77, 859.85, 808.12, 794.15, 
             746.61, 719.72, 709.59, 662.36, 695.06, 687.76, 0, 262.09, 347.17, 
             442.35, 453.76, 684.06, 638.13, 664.69, 721.68, 688.32, 653.87, 
             665.21, 680.52, 685.13, 0, 38.77, 264.4, 432.8, 408.33, 457.38, 
             474.23, 453.76, 570.74, 591.96, 593.7, 636.75, 585.43, 577.72, 
             0, 0, 92.65, 255.08, 388.66, 432.73, 418.19, 425.02, 436.3, 452.17, 
             489.17, 499.27, 500.93, 495.26, 0, 0, 0, 90.28, 309.44, 324.99, 
             357.05, 376.11, 412.2, 337.4, 338.54, 370.11, 389.95, 501.99, 
             0, 0, 0, 0, 106.55, 190.84, 216.41, 322.11, 337.05, 313.99, 325.03, 
             356.98, 381.47, 373.77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 198.84, 120.76, 204.33, 
             146.22, 289.93, 284.82, 337.22, 347.41, 337.29), .Dim = c(14L, 
                                                                       12L))

Points<-as.matrix(data)

open3d()
persp3d(x=PredBarTargets, y=GainTargets, z=Points, 
     col="green3", main="Total Points")
```

then I do get a title on the plot, but unfortunately the title moves around with mouse actions.

Does anyone know how to get the title text "Total Points" to be fixed at the top of the window such that it doesn't move? Also, if there's a way to associate the axis text with the axis that that has the numbers on it then that might be more readable.

Thanks

Comment: You want a title that disappears when the plot is rotated 90degrees around the z axis?

Comment: -1 Make this reproducible and I'll give you the point back. Use sample data from the package or generate examples in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done in rgl at the moment. You can only place text in 3d coordinates and have it rotate with the plot. Why not contact the maintainer of rgl and put this on a feature request list.

Note this Q is a duplicate of another question on SO.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that. Also, if this is a duplicate of another question I'm sorry but I didn't find it in the search engine or I wouldn't have asked it.

Comment: Why close something as a dupe and answer it yourself? Oh, *and* mention in the answer that you know it's a dupe. Absolutely inexplicable and irrational behavior. -1 if I really felt like playing that game....